# How to keep boudin (blood sausage) slices from disintegrating when pan-frying?

Tags: frying, sausages, frying-pan

I want to pan-fry some boudin slices and then put them on slices of baguette with some apple compote.

I have cooked boudin before and often, the boudin was at least a bit disintegrated by the end. I really need those slices to stay together and I was wandering what can I do to prevent it.

Comment: Could you cook the whole sausage, then slice and pan fry to brown it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several methods and this gave the best result:

I put the boudin in the freezer for 10 min then I sliced it.

I started to pan-fry on mid heat and as soon as the upper sides started swelling, I flipped them. I did this about 3 times to avoid the slices swelling asymmetrically.

Total cooking time: 10 min.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to cook the whole sausage, but you might get away with it

Preheat oven to 250 degrees

Sauté sausage until browned all over

Put in oven to finish

Make Apple sauce

Combine the sauce with the warm boudin

Comment: I won't have access to an oven.

Comment: You could go completely the other way and crumble it beforehand and quickly stir-fry it then just spread it on the baguette